# Array of doubles objective c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, double

Is there something like `NSMutableArray` that will take doubles directly without putting them inside the `@""`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can only put objects into an `NSMutableArray`. But you can wrap your doubles in `NSNumber` like so:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.12345]];
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:5.43210]];
```

Comment: That's what I thought. I just didn't know how to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can only insert objects into an NSMutableArray. Luckily, there is a class, NSNumber, that is used to wrap Objective-C primitives as objects. You can use the doubleValue method to get your primitive value back.

For example:

```
NSMutableArray *numArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.1f], nil];
double num = [[numArray objectAtIndex:0]doubleValue];
```